# Prevent Gson from returning null when deserializing empty strings

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using Gson to serialize and deserialize JSON. In my tests, I found that when I pass my `Gson` object an empty string, it returns `null` rather than throwing a `JsonParseException`.

How can I configure Gson so that it throws an error for empty strings?

---

Here is my deserializer:

```
public final class ProjectDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Project> {

    @Override
    public Project deserialize(final JsonElement jsonElement, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        final JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

        final Identifier name = context.deserialize(jsonObject.get("name"), Identifier.class);

        Optional<String> license;
        if (jsonObject.has("license")) {
            license = Optional.of(jsonObject.get("license").getAsString());
        } else {
            license = Optional.empty();
        }

        DependencyGroup dependencies;
        if (jsonObject.has("dependencies")) {
            dependencies = context.deserialize(jsonObject.get("dependencies"), DependencyGroup.class);
        } else {
            dependencies = DependencyGroup.of();
        }

        return Project.of(name, license, dependencies);
    }
}
```

Here is my `Gson` factory:

```
public static Gson gson() {

    final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

    // etc...

    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Project.class, new ProjectSerializer());
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Project.class, new ProjectDeserializer());

    // etc...

    return gsonBuilder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make it like that out of box. Currently `com.google.gson.Gson` has the following code protecting code:

```java
public <T> T fromJson(JsonReader reader, Type typeOfT) throws JsonIOException, JsonSyntaxException {
    boolean isEmpty = true;
    ...
    try {
      reader.peek();
      ...
    } catch (EOFException e) {
      /*
       * For compatibility with JSON 1.5 and earlier, we return null for empty
       * documents instead of throwing.
       */
      if (isEmpty) {
        return null;
      }
      throw new JsonSyntaxException(e);
```

Passing an empty or a blank string to the method makes the `reader.peek();` line to throw an `EOFException`, and the `isEmpty` flag is set to `true` at that moment. And this is why your deserializer has no any effect on it: it's not even invoked. This behavior was introduced in commit `25c6ae177b1ca56db7f3c29eb574bdd032a06165` [back in 2011](https://github.com/google/gson/commit/25c6ae177b1ca56db7f3c29eb574bdd032a06165) with the following commit message excerpt:

> For backwards compatibility, return null for the empty string.

What you can do is either making sure that you check deserialized objects for `null`, or (if centralized deserialization is possible for you [at least it should be]) make sure that `Gson.fromJson(JsonReader,Type)` is used for deserialization purposes: this is where you can inject a custom `JsonReader` wrapping `EOFException`s into `JsonSyntaxException`s that are not currently caught in that method (at least as of Gson 2.8.0). For example:

```java
public class EmptyStringFailFastJsonReader
        extends JsonReader {

    public EmptyStringFailFastJsonReader(final Reader in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonToken peek()
            throws IOException {
        try {
            return super.peek();
        } catch ( final EOFException ex ) {
            throw new JsonSyntaxException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

This would break the protecting code in Gson. A few examples below. The code that does not fail:

```java
gson.fromJson("", fooType);
gson.fromJson(new StringReader(""), fooType);
```

But the following one does:

```java
gson.fromJson(new EmptyStringFailFastJsonReader(new StringReader("")), fooType);
```

With the following exception message:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I think the best solution for my project is to have static methods for each type I might deserialize and do the check there.